# R.net error during evaluation - "subscript out of bounds"

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I am getting "subscript out of bounds" error when I run R script via R.net (input data from C# code). Strangely if I run the Rscript when same input data is provided by excel, it runs fine! Any ideas on why it would happen? I am sending "vardata" from C# code.

*

```
***Error in my.data.var.mat.1st[Pos.loc] <- my.data.var.1st : 
  subscript out of bounds***
```

*

Here is the code and associated information.

```
vardata <- structure(list(t = c(10, 10, 10, 10), f1j = c(0.25, 0, 0, 0.25
), f2j = c(0.25, 0, 0, 0.25), f3j = c(0.25, 0, 0, 0.25), f4j = c(0.25, 0, 0.25, 0.25), f5j = c(0, 0.25, 0, 0.25)), .Names = c("t", "f1j", "f2j", "f3j", "f4j", "f5j"), row.names = c(NA,-4L), class = "data.frame")

tolerance <- 0
Tau.Fij.opt.mat.1st <-  ifelse(vardata > tolerance ,vardata,0)  
Pos.list <- Tau.Fij.opt.mat.1st[Tau.Fij.opt.mat.1st>0] #get all values>0 
Pos.loc <- which(Tau.Fij.opt.mat.1st > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)  #get locations>0                 
Zero.list <- Tau.Fij.opt.mat.1st[Tau.Fij.opt.mat.1st==0] 
Zero.loc <- which(Tau.Fij.opt.mat.1st == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)  
my.data.var.1st <- Pos.list     # variables to be evaluated

Error.func.1st <- function(my.data.var.1st,Pos.loc,Zero.loc,Zero.list)  #my.data.var.1st,Pos.loc,Zero.loc,Zero.list
{
  #First convert vector(my.data.var) to MATRIX aand send it to calculate new MATRIX
  my.data.var.mat.1st <- matrix(,nrow = 4,ncol = 6,byrow = TRUE)

  my.data.var.mat.1st[Pos.loc] <- my.data.var.1st
  if(length(Zero.loc)>0)
  {
    my.data.var.mat.1st[Zero.loc] <- Zero.list
  }

 Error <- my.data.var.mat.1st
  }

AA <- Error.func.1st(my.data.var.1st,Pos.loc,Zero.loc,Zero.list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in my code. The input matrix from C# had to be transposed before being used. Hence, the error about "Subscript out of bounds". Setting this as closed.